# Is there a way to check if there exists a Pulsar producer with the same name on the same topic?

Tags: apache-pulsar, pulsar

Pulsar allows multiple producers to subscribe to the same topic only if they have different producer names. Is there a way to check if a producer with the same name (and same topic) already exists?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [stats](http://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/pulsar-admin/#stats-1) command from the [pulsar-admin CLI tool](http://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/pulsar-admin/) to list all of the producers attached to the topic as follows, then just look inside the `publishers` section of the JSON output for the `producerName`

```
root@6b40ffcc05ec:/pulsar# ./bin/pulsar-admin topics stats persistent://public/default/test-topic
{
  "msgRateIn" : 19.889469865137894,
  "msgThroughputIn" : 1253.0366015036873,
  "msgRateOut" : 0.0,
  "msgThroughputOut" : 0.0,
  "bytesInCounter" : 65442,
  "msgInCounter" : 1002,
  "bytesOutCounter" : 0,
  "msgOutCounter" : 0,
  "averageMsgSize" : 63.0,
  "msgChunkPublished" : false,
  "storageSize" : 65442,
  "backlogSize" : 0,
  "publishers" : [ {
    "msgRateIn" : 19.889469865137894,
    "msgThroughputIn" : 1253.0366015036873,
    "averageMsgSize" : 63.0,
    "chunkedMessageRate" : 0.0,
    "producerId" : 0,
    "metadata" : { },
    "producerName" : "standalone-3-1",
    "connectedSince" : "2020-08-06T15:51:48.279Z",
    "clientVersion" : "2.6.0",
    "address" : "/127.0.0.1:53058"
  } ],
  "subscriptions" : { },
  "replication" : { },
  "deduplicationStatus" : "Disabled"
}
```